# OBJ Loader THREE.JS Issue

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have an issue with OBJ Loader in THREE.JS.
I've wrote the following code:

```
   //Scene
scene = new THREE.Scene();

//Camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,1000);

//Renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth-5,window.innerHeight-5);
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);


//loader
loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load('../disk.obj',function(object){
   scene.add(object);
});
//Main loop
function init() {
   renderer.render(camera,scene);
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: you are not describing what the problem is.

Comment: The loader is not running..

Comment: When I render my code on the browser, I cant see what the loader should render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your javascript is in another file, you never call the init method. When you do, make sure the document is loaded with the window.onload line. You don't have any lights in your scene so of course it will be all black. Make sure you include the OBJLoader which is in the js/examples folder. Also make sure your object file is large enough or that the camera is looking at it.

Your HTML should be something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="three.js/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and your javascript file (main.js) should be something like this. replace of course

```
window.onload=function(){
  init();
  animate();
}

function init() {

  container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
  console.log(container)
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
  camera.position.z = 100;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
  scene.add( ambient );

  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
  directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
  scene.add( directionalLight );

  var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  loader.load( 'three.js/examples/obj/male02/male02.obj', function ( object ) {
    console.log(object);
    scene.add( object );
  } );

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();

}

function render() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your load callback try this

```
loader.load('', function( geom ){
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geom, yourmaterial);
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```